# Call a side effecting function only when atom value changes

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

What is the simplest way to trigger a side-effecting function to be called only when an `atom`'s value changes?

If I were using a `ref`, I think I could just do this:

```
(defn transform-item [x] ...)
(defn do-side-effect-on-change [] nil)

(def my-ref (ref ...))
(when (dosync (let [old-value @my-ref
                    _ (alter! my-ref transform-item)
                    new-value @my-ref]
                (not= old-value new-value)))
  (do-side-effect-on-change))
```

But this seems seems a bit roundabout, since I'm using a `ref` even though I am not trying to coordinate changes across multiple `ref`s. Essentially I am using it just to conveniently access the old and new value within a successful transaction.

I feel like I should be able to use an `atom` instead. Is there a solution simpler than this?

```
(def my-atom (atom ...))
(let [watch-key ::side-effect-watch
      watch-fn (fn [_ _ old-value new-value]
                 (when (not= old-value new-value)
                   (do-side-effect-on-change)))]
  (add-watch my-atom watch-key watch-fn)
  (swap! my-atom transform-item)
  (remove-watch watch-key))
```

This also seems roundabout, because I am adding and removing the watch around every call to `swap!`. But I need this, because I don't want a watch hanging around that causes the side-effecting function to be triggered when other code modifies the `atom`.

It is important that the side-effecting function be called exactly once per mutation to the atom, and only when the transform function `transform-item` actually returns a new value. Sometimes it will return the old value, yielding new change.

Comment: Your `atom` solution doesn't even achieve the desired effect; if the atom's value is changed by another thread before that `swap!` completes, the watch will fire once for that change and again once the `swap!` completes.

Comment: Good point! The add-watch and remove-watch are not wrapped in a transaction, so I have not actually isolated the watching to this particular call to `swap!`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(when (not= @a (swap! a transform))
  (do-side-effect))
```

But you should be very clear about what concurrency semantics you need. For example another thread may modify the atom between reading it and swapping it:

1. a = 1
2. Thread 1 reads a as 1
3. Thread 2 modifies a to 2
4. Thread 1 swaps a from 2 to 2
5. Thread 1 determines 1 != 2 and calls do-side-effect

It is not clear to me from the question whether this is desirable or not desirable. If you do not want this behavior, then an atom just will not do the job unless you introduce concurrency control with a lock.

Seeing as you started with a ref and asked about an atom, I think you have probably given some thought to concurrency already. It seems like from your description the ref approach is better:

```
(when (dosync (not= @r (alter r transform))
  (do-side-effect))
```

Is there a reason you don't like your ref solution?

If the answer is "because I don't have concurrency" Then I would encourage you to use a ref anyway. There isn't really a downside to it, and it makes your semantics explicit. IMO programs tend to grow and to a point where concurrency exists, and Clojure is really great at being explicit about what should happen when it exists. (For example oh I'm just calculating stuff, oh I'm just exposing this stuff as a web service now, oh now I'm concurrent).

In any case, bear in mind that functions like alter and swap! return the value, so you can make use of this for concise expressions.

Comment: Thanks for this. The reason I don't like my ref solution is because I thought refs were reserved for "coordinated" state, as per the docs, so I thought I must be doing it wrong to use them just in order to trigger side effects on a change. But sounds like it's the best way to go, since the atom semantics you describe do not serve my situation. I will now weild my dosync proudly, rather than with shame & doubt.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same situation and just come up 2 solutions.

#### state field `:changed?`

Keeping a meanless `:changed` mark in atom to track swap function. And take the return value of `swap!` to see if things changed. For example:

```
(defn data (atom {:value 0 :changed? false}))

(let [{changed? :changed?} (swap! data (fn [data] (if (change?) 
                                                    {:value 1 :changed? true} 
                                                    {:value 0 :change? false})))]
  (when changed? (do-your-task)))
```

#### exception based

You can throw an Exception in swap function, and catch it outside:

```
(try
  (swap! data (fn [d] (if (changed?) d2 (ex-info "unchanged" {})))
  (do-your-task)
  (catch Exception _
    ))
```